# How to work map a name to an ip address on my Windows?

Tags: asp.net, windows, url, hosts, hosts-file

I have a website hosted on a server and I can access it using the below:

```
http://<ip address>/sites/home.aspx
```

On my PC (Windows XP), I'd like to be able to map a name like "hello.world" to this ip address so that I can use

```
http://hello.world/sites/home.aspx
```

How would that be possible?

I found the hosts file and added a map like below but still it doesn't work:

```
<ip address> hello.world
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The host file is the one think, the second think is to map it on IIS. Normally what you have done must make it play all ready, but because is not working means that both must exist and the host map and the iis let this name to reflect the site.

So go to the IIS, on this site, right click, properties, find the "web site identification", on the Ip Address cick on Advanced and add this name to the identities for your web site.